# Installed Ubuntu in dual boot, then tried to reinstall and now can't boot any live USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

Two days ago I formatted my second partition and installed Ubuntu on it as dual boot. It worked fine that day.

The next day when I tried to boot into Ubuntu I had some error. So I formatted it hoping to reinstall it but this time I wasn't even able to boot into my USB to try it.

I flashed Zorin OS onto my USB and it was having the same problem. I realized I was having the same problem with any iso file and the same error appeared for all of them.

I thought the problem was with my USB and tried other methods which don't involve USB. My USB is fine. I tried Rufus and Etcher but no luck. I need help or I would never be able to install ubuntu or any iso file. I love ubuntu like you all and my low spec laptop can't run a VM properly.

This is how it looks when I start to boot:

[image: firmware related errors followed by boot messages]

[image: boot messages, looking for cdrom image]

[image: hp logo + ubuntu logo]

Comment: I don't see any fatal error in those boot messages - at least it's evidently continuing. Does the boot just freeze at the screen in your third picture? (how long do you wait? Live USB boot can be slow) If so, I would guess the actual problem occurs later and there's no information about it. Are you sure it's not a problem with the USB stick? They are quite unreliable. What other methods or means of checking your USB did you try? Did you try another USB?

Comment: Enter your BIOS and find the "Reset to factory defaults", select it, and then see if you can boot to USB again. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: I started it and waited for 2 hours No luck. I used virtual usb drive by formating small volume into fat no luck

Comment: What model HP? What video card/chip? What version of Ubuntu? If very new system best to use 21.04. And 20.04.3 will be out soon, Aug 26th. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule

Comment: @heynnema it's still showing same error

Comment: Remove all CD/DVD discs, and all USB devices EXCEPT for the Ubuntu Live USB. Then try to boot either the HDD/SSD or the Live USB from the BIOS boot menu. Report back. Does Windows still boot?

Answer (score -2):

can you check in the bios the boot order ?

Usually when you can't start any iso from usb is because the bios load the hard disk first. so all you have to do is to check the order and set the usb as first boot order

Comment: in that case Windows would boot I think - looks like the Ubuntu system is trying to boot

Comment: I waited for 2 to 3 hours no luck